# ModelMapper can not mapping a method 'parent' named

Tags: mapping, parent, modelmapper

I'm tested on ModelMapper 0.7.5.

If a model have below conditions then ModelMapper can’t not mapping them.

- a method name is ‘parent’ and return self class
- a method name is ‘parentPath’ and return string

The test code is

```
public static class SomeModelMapper extends ModelMapper {
    public void init() {
        getConfiguration().setMatchingStrategy(MatchingStrategies.STANDARD);
    }
}

@Data
public static class Dto1 {
    private Dto1 another;
    private String anothorPath;
}

@Data
public static class Dto2 {
    private Dto2 parent;
    private String parentPath;
}

@Test
public void testMapping() {
    SomeModelMapper mapper = new SomeModelMapper();
    mapper.init();
    Map map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("anothorPath", "x");

    Dto1 dto1 = mapper.map(map, Dto1.class);
    assertThat(dto1.getAnothorPath(), is("x")); // success

    map.clear();
    map.put("parentPath", "y");
    Dto2 dto2 = mapper.map(map, Dto2.class); // failed
    assertThat(dto2.getParentPath(), is("y"));
}
```

error message is

```
org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Error mapping java.util.HashMap to com.semogyo.api.web.mapper.Object2ObjectMapperTest$Dto2

1 error

    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.throwMappingExceptionIfErrorsExist(Errors.java:374)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:69)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.mapInternal(ModelMapper.java:497)
    at org.modelmapper.ModelMapper.map(ModelMapper.java:340)
    at com.semogyo.api.web.mapper.Object2ObjectMapperTest.testMapping(Object2ObjectMapperTest.java:202)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:160)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:119)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:42)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:234)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:74)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Failed to set value 'Object2ObjectMapperTest.Dto2(parent=null, parentPath=null)' on com.semogyo.api.web.mapper.Object2ObjectMapperTest$Dto2.setParentPath()

1 error
    at org.modelmapper.internal.Errors.toMappingException(Errors.java:258)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoImpl$MethodMutator.setValue(PropertyInfoImpl.java:118)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.setDestinationValue(MappingEngineImpl.java:249)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.propertyMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:180)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.typeMap(MappingEngineImpl.java:131)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:101)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.MappingEngineImpl.map(MappingEngineImpl.java:60)
    ... 30 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: argument type mismatch
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
    at org.modelmapper.internal.PropertyInfoImpl$MethodMutator.setValue(PropertyInfoImpl.java:116)
    ... 35 more
```

Why I can not use the "parent" of method name?

Answer (score 1):

You can use "parent" as you like but not in this case. If you change your property name "parent" to other token it works (for example "father"). But try to change your other example Dto1 like this and look what happens:(property "anothor" to "another"):

```
@Data
public static class Dto1 {
    private Dto1 another;
    private String anotherPath;
}
```

And your HashMap (anothorPath -> anotherPath):

```
Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("anotherPath", "x");
Dto1 dto1 = mapper.map(map, Dto1.class);
```

It happens the same error:

```
Caused by: org.modelmapper.MappingException: ModelMapper mapping errors:

1) Failed to set value 'Test.Dto1(another=null, anotherPath=null)' on com.example.Test$Dto1.setAnotherPath()
... same trace error
```

Why? Simply, as same as your sample it is generating a infinite loop.

1. ModelMapper maps String parentPath
2. ModelMapper maps DTO2 parent -> String ParentPath.
3. ModelMapper maps DTO2 parent -> DTO2 parent -> String parentPath
4. ModelMapper maps DTO2 parent -> DTO2 parent -> DTO2 parent -> String parentPath
5. ....Infinite loop....This seems it will not stop...

Let me explain you why. ModelMapper looks `String parentPath` accessor and it is mappable, then it tries to map `Dto2 parent` and so on... If you put another name to `Dto2` it doesn't try to map `Dto2` and the loop will not be generated.

### Examples

#### Case 1

Imagine your classes were like this:

```
@Data
public static class Dto1 {
    private Dto2 another;
    private String parentPath;      
    
}

@Data
public static class Dto2 {
    private Dto1 parent;
    private String parentPath;
    
}
```

The output would be `Test.Dto2(parent=Test.Dto1(another=null, parentPath=y), parentPath=y)`. It would map both `String parent`Dto1 and Dto2.

#### Case 2

But in case your classes were like the next:

```
@Data
public static class Dto1 {
    private Dto2 parent;
    private String parentPath;      
}

@Data
public static class Dto2 {
    private Dto1 parent;
    private String parentPath;
}
```

Again is generating the error, the same infinite loop.

### Conclusion

This kind of mappings are not supported maybe the author thought that it would be better like this to be consistent, I don't know.